# About how fast is indexeddb

Tags: performance, html, indexeddb

I am deciding if I should use IndexedDB. I am going to use it on a large scale, so can somebody tell me if the performance will be reasonable with 2-3 object stores, several indexes (probably 5+) on each object store, a few hundred records, each with dozens of properties, and 20-30 MB of data? I don't need huge speed, I just want it to be reasonable, faster than accessing a database on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it!!! I´m about to finish an off-line app that uses IndexedDB in a relatively big scale, I´m using 16 tables/objectStores and with AJAX I´m able to connect to the server, create the all the objectStores and download/sync 260 000 records from sql server in about a minute, most of it is spent doing the queries on the server side.
Once the data is on your side the management is virtually light-speed, of course decreases a bit in ARM devices (as expected) but what a heck, it works fine and it works in every machine (win, mac, linux, android) as Firefox is always ahead in the latest specs (chrome is almost there to).
For more info visit [Kristof Degrave](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/) blog he knows it all.

Comment: Do you recommend use localforage js as a wrapper for storage calls?

Comment: I would. It's very popular and defaults to using IndexedDB.

Comment: I developed an App that works 100% offline with syncing. IndexedDB / LocalForage decreases significantly in ARM / Android (11 and below) devices, not a bit. You have to use localStore + memory cache as indexing mechanism to avoid huge freezes. While in any browser it will work 20 times faster. Another alternative for gaining speed is to use queries with batch processing. Eg. https://opkode.com/blog/2021-05-05-mergebounce-indexeddb/